# How to use TSL maps for Civ 5 (making True Start Locations work)?

Tags: civilization-5

Some maps for Civilization 5 are advertised as 'TSL', featuring True Start Locations. An example is http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=388696 . How do I make these work? With the map above, I've tried going Main Menu > Single Player > Set up game, and then selecting this map, and then ticking load scenario. But that doesn't work.

I'm using Mac G&K if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is this:

1. Go to MODS
2. Check the mods required for the TSL to work
3. Click NEXT
4. Click Single Player
5. Click Set Up
6. Load the proper map
7. Verify the button "Load Scenario" is checked!!!!
     (This will appear where it shows which map you are using)

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Mac G&K. Do TSL maps only work on Windows?